# What are the ways to get included in Google Alerts mails

Tags: google

There is a news website / blog - I'll call it the Site from now on. The site mention a keyword in one of its articles.

I add a [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) for the keyword, but I do not get any alert for the word from The Site. Furthermore, searching the keyword in the [news section](http://news.google.com/) don't getting any results from The Site.

The Site has a sitemap, that indexed by Google every x minutes. And in the [main search](http://www.google.com/), searching for a news title bring the item on the top.

What are the best ways to get included in Google Alerts mails?

Answer (score 1):

Google Alerts typically only show the newest posts/pages that the crawler finds. If your pages are old, they won't show up.

Comment: I'm talking about the new pages.